# FIWARE: Scaling IoT Agents

Tags: fiware

If one had a large FIWARE IoT system with a smart city's worth of connected devices, how would the IoT Agents be scaled?

Would the IoT Agents share state with each other like the Context Brokers or is the recommended strategy to divide devices among the IoT Agents?

If it's the former, are there any recommendations on the number of devices per agent? If it's the latter, are there some settings for sharing state?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to assign numbers as you suggest, as the correct architecture for your system will depend on the throughput needed, which in turn depends on the rate and latency of your devices.

As a general rule you should keep the architecture as simple as possible, only adding in sharding and duplication of resources you are unable to get throughput with a simpler architecture.

You can find some scaling [recipes](https://github.com/smartsdk/smartsdk-recipes) and [architectures](https://github.com/smartsdk/architecture-diagrams) for FIWARE on the Smart SDK GitHub.